# How to disable pop-ups and notifications?

Tags: notifications, notification-bar, navigation, popup, mute

I have Android 5.1. I use my phone as navigation when I`m driving and I need to disable all notifications and pop-ups. I know I can block notifications from settings, but this takes too much time to disable all apps and enable them again after driving. Also, Facebook and other apps have those pop-ups ("Chat heads" ), which are really disturbing.

Is there any app that can prevent them to appear on my screen ?

Comment: Does Screen pinning not help here?

Comment: Not with "Chad heads".. it looks like facebook is over that feature (in fact over Android) :)) .

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to disable the heads up notification, you can try [HeadsOff](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jamworks.noheadsup) app on the Play store which effectively removes any "pop up" notifications from the top.

For something more granular, try [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) which allows you to control notifications for indivdual applications.

Comment: Is there any free version of Tasker or something like this?

Comment: Try Automate. It's a great alternative albeit with a smaller toolset of controls.

Comment: Thanks.. it would work if it would be able to acces a specific activity from an app.. unfortunately.. it is not possibple :( due to android restrictions

Comment: You can try using Automate to set the state of notification to off for all apps when the navigation app is in the foreground.

Comment: I tried HeadsOff -> doesn`t work (facebook messages still appearing on my screen)

Comment: I tried automate.. there is an option to hide notification bar, but it didn`t helped and I can`t find any notification state (other than a condition..)